# using native replication on postgreSQL or using Slony to replicate dbs

Tags: postgresql-9.4

Can anyone help me on the question why they're using Slony to replicate databases, but not using PostgreSQL's native replication? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Slony is useful when you only need to replicate some of the tables in your database, or when you are replicating data between different versions of Postgres. (There are other uses, but those are the uses I've used it for.)

The new replication work that was done in 9.4 and is continuing in 9.5 will make these previous uses of Slony mute.